# Can we relax the hypothesis of Uniqueness theorem for Fourier series?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

I know this fact: "Suppose that $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb T)$ and $\hat{f}(n)=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb  Z,$ then $f=0 $ all most everywhere on $\mathbb T$."

> My Question is: Suppose that $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb T)$ and $\hat{f}(n)=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z \setminus \{ 0 \},$ and $\hat{f}(0) \in \mathbb C.$ Can we say $f=0$ all most every where on $\mathbb T$ ? If not (example?),  what can we say about $f$?

Edit:  In view of comments below, how to show $f$ is constant a. e. on $\mathbb T$?

Comment: Do you really mean $f=0$ almost everywhere? While it is not hard to show that $f$ must be constant almost everywhere, there is a very simple counterexample to show that $f\neq0$.

Comment: The function $f=1$ is a counterexample. If you want to figure out what actually happens under your weaker hypotheses, let $g=f-\hat f(0)$ and note that $\hat g(n)=0$ for all $n$...

Comment: @Jason: Thanks, I mean that  only. But I do not follow what are you  suggesting. Thanks

Comment: I'll provide an answer.

Comment: @Jason: Thanks, I think I got it: Would you please let me know how to show $f$ is constant all most everywhere?

Comment: @Jason: Thanks;

Answer (score 1):

Following David C. Ullrich's suggestion in the comments, let $g=f-\hat f(0)$. It is fairly straightforward to show $\hat g(n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$, so by the usual uniqueness theorem, $g=0$ almost everywhere. This implies $f=\hat f(0)$ almost everywhere, i.e. $f$ is constant almost everywhere.

Comment: In David's Suggestion; $f=1$ and so $\hat{g}=0$. But for arbitrary, how does it follow?

Comment: If $f=1,$ then we may write $g=f- \hat{f}(0) f.$ And hence $\hat{g}=0.$ But for any $f$ I do not see this? Or am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Ignore $f=1$, as David's counterexample is valid for any $\hat f(0)\neq0$. Just calculate $\hat g(n)$!

Comment: No, $f$ was not equal to $1$ in my suggestion. You need to learn about sentences.